# Understanding TI's ProjectSpec Files -- What do <property name = ""> <file path = ""> do and where are the environ variables defined?

Tags: makefile, project, texas-instruments

Here is an interesting snippet of TI's .projectspec file for the MMWave SDK Out-of-Box (OOO) demo:

```
    compilerBuildOptions="
    -I${PROJECT_ROOT}
    -I${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/include
    -I${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages
    -I${TI_PRODUCTS_DIR}/mathlib_c674x_3_1_2_1/packages


    <!-- Project properties -->
    <property name="type" value="rtsc"/>
    <property name="products" value="com.ti.rtsc.SYSBIOS:6.73.01.01;com.ti.MMWAVE_SDK:03.06.00.00-LTS;"/>
    <property name="xdcToolsVersion" value="3.50.08.24_core"/>
    <property name="target" value="ti.targets.elf.C674"/>
    <property name="platform" value="ti.platforms.c6x:IWR68XX:false:600"/>
    <property name="endianness" value="little"/>
    <property name="output_format" value="elf"/>
    <property name="buildProfile" value="release"/>
    <property name="configuroOptions" value="--compileOptions &quot;--enum_type=int &quot; "/>

    <!-- Project files -->
    <file path="${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages/ti/demo/xwr68xx/mmw/dss/dss_main.c" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
    <file path="${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages/ti/demo/xwr68xx/mmw/dss/mmw_dss.cfg" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
    <file path="${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages/ti/demo/xwr68xx/mmw/dss/mmw_dss_linker.cmd" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
    <file path="${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages/ti/datapath/dpc/objectdetection/objdetdsp/src/objectdetection.c" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
    <file path="${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages/ti/platform/xwr68xx/c674x_linker.cmd" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
    <file path="${COM_TI_MMWAVE_SDK_INSTALL_DIR}/packages/ti/board/antenna_geometry.c" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
```

I can't seem to find any info on what the following comnmands do:

```
 <property name = " " , value = " ">
 <filepath="" openOnCreation="false" excludeFromBuild="false" action="copy"/>
```

and where I can find the definitions of the environment variables like ${PROJECT_ROOT}.

Could anyone explain these or at least link me to the documents? TI's customer support is not very helpful in this regard...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is vaguely documented here https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/ccs_projectspecs.html

In general they refer to the schema file

> For additional information on the structure of the projectSpec files and documentation on the attributes, refer to the XML schema file for projectspecs named projectSpec.xsd. The file can be found in the directory
> <ccs_install_dir>\ccsv\eclipse\plugins\com.ti.ccstudio.project.templates_\schema

The `<property name=...` is different setting in your project, You can find the same properties, if you open the "project settings" dialog in the IDE after you imported the project.

the `<file ...` is maninly for importing files into your project, the `action` mainly tells if you want to copy the file or link to the original file.

A small snippet from one of my own projectspec files

```
<pathVariable name="SRC_ROOT" path="..\..\.." scope="project" />
<!-- In traditinal eclipse projects the PROJECT_LOC is the folder in the git tree where .ccsproject was, with projectspec this points into a
     worksspace folder, so we need a new pointer to where the .projectspec files is located for some references, I name this PROJECT_ORIGIN -->
<pathVariable name="PROJECT_ORIGIN" path="." scope="project" />

<file action="link" targetDirectory="" path="SRC_ROOT/product/cpu2/Main.c" />
<file action="link" targetDirectory="drivers" path="SRC_ROOT/shared/tms/uart.c" createVirtualFolders="true"/>
```

the `<pathvariable...` will create variables, that you will find below "linked resources" in the "project property dialog" in the IDE.
**Note** that relative path references is relative to the location of the .projectspec file, and not to the resulting workspace.

`<file action="link" targetDirectory="" path="SRC_ROOT/product/cpu2/Main.c" />` creates a link from my workspace environment to a sourcefile in my git repo (where SRC_ROOT points to)

`<file action="link" targetDirectory="drivers" path="SRC_ROOT/shared/tms/uart.c" createVirtualFolders="true"/>` Does the same except here it also creates a virtual folder inside my workspace where it will place the link.

You last question about `${PROJECT_ROOT}`. This is a variable defined inside the project, some are userdefined and others like the `CG_TOOL_ROOT`is autocreated by CCS, please note that these variables is not expanded from the .projectspec file on import, the buildoption vallue will be the literal string as quoted above including all the `${` characters, those variables is only evaluated/expanded when the build is running.